# Angular JS button ng click to one function vs desktop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I'm using `angular material` for my app. I want a button to do different things when executed on a phone or tablet vs a desktop view.

For example if clicked on desktop then print value1 from model or if clicked on mobile or tab then print value2. Basically I want to know how I can trigger 2 different functions for desktop vs mobile or tab.

Answer (score 1):

Use the layout options explained here: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/options (scroll down to show & hide)  to render the button twice, one with ng-click calling the function you want for desktop and the second with ng-click calling the function you want to use for mobile.

These are just directives you can add to any element, so you'd use something like

```
<md-button hide-xs ng-click="desktopFunction()">Desktop Button</md-button>
<md-button show-xs ng-click="mobileFunction()">Mobile Button</md-button>
```

Comment: I thought along these lines but no other way like ngTouch or something?